# Why do Microsoft use 14.667 rather than 14 as the ControlContentThemeFontSize?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my Windows Store app project I am looking at **generic.xaml** which contains all of the built in styles for the default controls.

I'm noticing a lot of the font size styles use .667 as a suffix rather than a whole number for the font size, why is this? What is special about using 14.667 over 14 for example? And not all of them are like this, some are whole numbers..

**Some examples I have seen:**

```
<x:Double x:Key="ControlContentThemeFontSize">14.667</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="HubSectionHeaderThemeFontSize">26.667</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="SettingsFlyoutHeaderThemeFontSize">26.667</x:Double>
etc, etc
```

For reference someone has uploaded the contents of the generic's file here:
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/wiki/XAML-Native-Win8-Store-Apps-Style

Comment: I think that because these values come from pt values ... 14,667 px is 11pt, 26.667px is 20 pt ... etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a simple side-effect of different units-of-measure.  XAML uses a unit of 1/96 inch.  Font sizes are normally expressed in points, 1/72 inch.  So 14.667 == 14.667 / 96 * 72 = 11.000 points.

Comment: Hell I thought it was the Scottish rampant lion this whole time.

Comment: It is the logo of the KNVB (Royal Dutch Football Association).  It is going to take another 4 years before they encounter a Frenchman :)  Semi-final game against Argentina on Wednesday.